# Spark Group By Key to (Key,List) Pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to group some data by key where the value would be a list:

Sample data:

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
```

Expected result:

```
(A,(1,2))
(B,(1,2))
```

I am able to do this with the following code:

```
data.groupByKey().mapValues(List(_))
```

The problem is that when I then try to do a Map operation like the following:

```
groupedData.map((k,v) => (k,v(0)))
```

It tells me I have the wrong number of parameters.

If I try:

```
groupedData.map(s => (s(0),s(1)))
```

It tells me that "(Any,List(Iterable(Any)) does not take parameters"

No clue what I am doing wrong. Is my grouping wrong? What would be a better way to do this?

Scala answers only please. Thanks!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're almost there. Just replace `List(_)` with `_.toList`

```
data.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList)
```

Comment: Great! That worked. My real issues is that after I had the key list pair I was trying to execute functions on the list with map instead of mapValues. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I thought groupBy is preferred over reduceByKey. But today I read [some articles](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) indicating the opposite. So which one is true?

Comment: @Matthias There is no good answer for that without some context. Depending on a language, API, and operation any of these can be a valid choice.

Comment: Yeah, hard topic but important to understand this and read as much as you can about it :) btw: can you check [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033661/are-jupyter-notebook-executors-distributed-dynamically). I guess you can answer that one.

Answer (score 6):

When you write an anonymous inline function of the form

```
ARGS => OPERATION
```

the entire part before the arrow (`=>`) is taken as the argument list. So, in the case of

```
(k, v) => ...
```

the interpreter takes that to mean a function that takes two arguments. In your case, however, you have a single argument which happens to be a tuple (here, a `Tuple2`, or a `Pair` - more fully, you appear to have a list of `Pair[Any,List[Any]]`). There are a couple of ways to get around this. First, you can use the sugared form of representing a pair, wrapped in an extra set of parentheses to show that this is the single expected argument for the function:

```
((x, y)) => ...
```

or, you can write the anonymous function in the form of a partial function that matches on tuples:

```
groupedData.map( case (k,v) => (k,v(0)) )
```

Finally, you can simply go with a single specified argument, as per your last attempt, but - realising it is a tuple - reference the specific field(s) within the tuple that you need:

```
groupedData.map(s => (s._2(0),s._2(1)))  // The key is s._1, and the value list is s._2
```