# Apache Spark - How to use groupBy groupByKey to form a (Key, List) pair

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, name: string]` in hand 
 and sample data in it looks like:

```
(1, "City1")
(2, "City3")
(1, "CityX")
(4, "CityZ")
(2, "CityN")
```

I am trying to form a output like

```
(1, ("City1", "CityX"))
(2, ("City3", "CityN"))
(4, ("CityZ"))
```

I tried the following variants

```
df.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList).show(20, false)
df.groupBy("id").show(20, false)
df.rdd.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList).show(20, false)
df.rdd.groupBy("id").show(20, false)
```

All of them complain about either `groupBy` or `groupByKey` being ambiguous or method not found errors. Any help is appreciated.

I tried the solution posted in [Spark Group By Key to (Key,List) Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344455/spark-group-by-key-to-key-list-pair), however that doesn't work for me and it fails with the following error:

```
<console>:88: error: overloaded method value groupByKey with alternatives:
  [K](func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,K], encoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[K])org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[K,org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  [K](func: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => K)(implicit evidence$3: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[K])org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset[K,org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to ()
```

Thanks.

Edit:

I did try the following:

```
val result = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("name"))
```

which gives

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, collect_list(node): array<string>]
```

I am not sure how to use this collect_list type .. I am trying to dump this to a file by doing

```
result.rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("test")
```

and I see the following

```
(1, WrappedArray(City1, CityX))
(2, WrappedArray(City3, CityN))
(4, WrappedArray(CityZ))
```

How do I dump this as the following ?

```
(1, (City1, CityX))
(2, (City3, CityN))
(4, (CityZ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an RDD of pairs, then you can use combineByKey(). To do this you have to pass 3 methods as arguments.

Method 1 takes a String, for example 'City1' as input, will add that String to an empty List and return that list
Method 2 takes a String, for example 'CityX' and one of the lists created by the previous method. Add the String to the list and return the list.
Method 3 takes 2 lists as input. It returns a new list with all the values from the 2 argument lists

combineByKey will then return an RDD>.

However in your case you are starting off with a DataFrame, which I do not have much experience with. I imagine that you will need to convert it to an RDD in order to use combineByKey()

Comment: Note, for best results when using combineByKey it helps if the data is partitioned

Comment: thanks will try it out. I also stumbled upon aggregateByKey(). From DF I can probably do foreachRDD and use the above suggested approach on RDDs

Comment: aggregateByKey() should work too. I always use combineByKey as a matter of habit as it is more general and so can be applied to more situations, but that is just me.   : )